# Programmatically created window appears but doesn't respond to touch events

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm creating my app without the MainWindow nib, and after updating to the new SDK, my app completely broke. In the main() function of main.m I have:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

Here's the relevant bits of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in AppDelegate.m

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *nav = ...;
UITableViewController *table = ...;

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav, table, nil];

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When the app launches, the tab bar is visible and so is the view in the first tab. However, all touch events are either not being registered or not being passed to the window itself. I subclassed UIWindow and set `window` to be an instance of it. In this subclass, I overrode the sendEvent: method to log to the console whenever it was called. Nothing is showing up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I figured it out. Hope this helps someone. These are the first couple lines in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
window.screen = [UIScreen mainScreen]; // this fixes the problem
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try to modify the fourth parameter from "nil" to the application delegate name in main.c

For example
Modify UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil) to 
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"HelloWorldAppDelegate")

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and what helped me was adding

```
[window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

...I had only been adding the view instead of the whole view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when removing the mainwindow.xib and creating the window programmatically: I still had that line:

[self.window addSubview:rootcontroller.view];

Removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to use:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Rather than:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
```