# Root View Controller items are not clickable

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

After some great trouble, I was finally able to load my first Navigation / ViewController, only now none of the sub items are clickable. I mean, I have a two text fields, two buttons, and a switch, but none of them do anything when clicked. I know it is not a problem with my xib file, as these elements behave in the xib simulator for iPad.

This is all the code my application uses so far, and I don't see why it should not be clickable.

MainWindow.xib = empty nib file

> int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
>   @"iPadAppDelegate");

application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

> ```
> self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
>
> UIViewController *login = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPadLoginView" bundle:nil]; 
>
> UINavigationController *nav_controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login];
>
> self.window.rootViewController = nav_controller;
> [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
>
>
> return YES;
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
```

with

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Replace

```
self.window.rootViewController = nav_controller;
```

with

```
[self.window addSubview:nav_controller.view];
```

Comment: Thanks. I found something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373729/programmatically-created-window-appears-but-doesnt-respond-to-touch-events

window.screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];

is a little more compact